# How to add a new method to a laravel facade that the default adapter doesn't have

Tags: php, laravel, inversion-of-control

Let's say I have a specific Filesystem that has a multiple-deleting method that could delete a bunch of files in just one request. However, the Storage facade will iterate the paths and delete them one by one. Is there a way to add a new method like `deleteMultipleFiles` in the filesystem adapter that could be called with the facade, without changing the code of the laravel framework?

Update:
I am trying to delete millions of files from cloud storage, but the default delete API will delete only one file in one request, so I need a new method to do this. The default cloud disk package is using `League\Flysystem\Filesystem;` which don't have macro method to extend it.

Update:

Here is how I am doing to achieve this:

Put the new method in the *Adapter.php* of the disk, and call it with this `Storage::disk('xxx')->getAdapter()->newMethod()`

Comment: You can use `Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem::macro` and create your own `macro`, in this case `deleteMultipleFiles`, but if you change the disk (this is where `Filesystem` is on), you are going to call a non existing method or a method not working anymore for other disks. It is more complex than it seems. Maybe the solution is in other place. Can you explain a little more which `Filesystem` are you trying to use and you have to change ?

Comment: @matiaslauriti Thanks for your help. I have updated the question, and I am about to use this in a console command, so I think it should not fail on other disks.

Answer (score 1):

You can add macros to certain Illuminate classes like the Filesystem. Just add them in the `boot` method of `AppServiceProvider`. Note that you can adjust the arguments (`$args` and `$ifAny` on this case) however you like,

```php
use Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem;

class AppServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        Filesystem::macro('deleteMultipleFiles', function ($args, $ifAny) {
            // Do what you need to do.
        });
    }
}
```

Then, use it like this.

```php
File::deleteMultipleFiles($args, $ifAny);
```